# Connecting Facebook to my Java Servlet

Tags: java, facebook, jakarta-ee

I followed an instruction fro a user here, about allowing users to automatically login using their facebook account in the app that i am creating . But, i am having errors.

```
    <%
    String fbURL = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=651066068265632&     

    redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode("651066068265632") + "&scope=email";
    %>
```

this is the new error that I got:

> The redirect_uri URL must be absolute

also:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I tried to get a new example from Graph API, and i downloaded the whole project, but this is the error i am getting::

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 191
>      }
>   }
>   what should i do?

Comment: it seems you're at least missing a `"` and a declaration of `redirect_uri` and more code than what's shown

Comment: this is my error:                      Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Comment: i did some servlet thing too, and used org.jason, am i going in the right place? Is there any other easier way?

Comment: you probably need to post your actual code here. Also, the two errors you describe are quite different, under what circumstances does each occur?

Comment: Check your Facebook app settings too. Facebook login will only work on the domains that you specified there.  You can add additional domains, but you can't redirect to some other location.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/ or use already existing interfaces like RestFB or Spring (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/)